# C# gRPC code first API streaming from client

Tags: c#, grpc, code-first, protobuf-net, grpc-c#

Need a little help. I am using code first approach to gRPC. Here is my service definition:

```cs
[ServiceContract]
public interface IFileStorageService
{
    [OperationContract]
    Task<StoreFileResponse> StoreFile(IAsyncStreamReader<FileChunk> requestStream, CallContext context);
}
```

I want to be able to create a code first client by using following method

```cs
serviceCollection.AddCodeFirstGrpcClient<IFileStorageService>(...)
```

My problem is that when I then try to use the client by injecting IFileStorageService in my client app, I have no idea where to get the IAsyncStreamReader from.

Can anyone help me ?  Cheers!

Comment: I first added an answer because I thought you do not know how to create the client. But re-reading your question, what do you mean by *I have no idea where to get the IAsyncStreamReader from*? This is literally a parameter for the method that you defined yourself. Just add an implementation of the `IAsyncStreamReader` the way you imagined it to work, and pass it to the method? Also, you do not need to inject it at all into the service? It is part of the `OperationContract`, not the `IFileStorageService` interface.

Comment: What do you mean by inject it all into the service ?

Comment: You said *"when I then try to use the client by injecting IFileStorageService in my client app, I have no idea where to get the IAsyncStreamReader from"*. Why do you need to inject IAsyncStreamReader into the service? How would you even do that? You inject the IFileStorageService, and when you want to use it. you call the StoreFile method from it and give it your IAsyncStreamReader which is a parameter of the method.